# My interpretation of the MVVM-concept in WPF (In relation to presenters)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvp

Is this a correct interpretation of the MVVM-concept?

- DataTemplates -> View
- DependencyObject (Controls, ListView etc) -> ViewModel
- DataContext -> Model

If I were to create my own ViewModel, it would replace the actual controls and need explicit templating?

The word 'Model' in ViewModel is not reffering to the actual Model (such as in DomainModel)?

To the model I add Presenters as well, which I see as utility-classes to elevate and expose properties etc to the view. Can you say that a ViewModel is a top-down representation (a model of a view) and that a Presenter is more of a ModelView, a bottom-up representation (a view of a model)?

In that case I would have to modify the above to this:

- ...
- DataContext -> Presenter
- Presenter -> Model

And I wouldn't generally derive from DependencyObject to create my custom presentation-wrappers, but only to create my custom generic models of views such as controls rather then views of my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually MVVM is meant to be interpreted this way:

View  -> Controls, DataTemplates etc.
Model -> Your actual data model (database, or whatever)
ViewModel -> Exposes properties and commands that the View can use for DataBinding

That means, your View has the ViewModel as a DataContext, the ViewModel's properties reflect the Model's data, and the ViewModel's Commands operate on the Model. In simple cases, Model and ViewModel are sometimes the same.

An overview can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx
You can also find quite a few examples on building an MVVM Application if you look for it.

Comment: I think the word ViewModel is missleading. Would'nt ModelView be a better word for it? It's a view of a model and not a model of a view. I think of a model of a view more like a Button and the view strictly as a graphical representation. I know it's against the common interpretation... but from my perspective it makes more sense.

Comment: The article i referred to explains it so that the ViewModel is an abstraction of the view, and as such a "model of the view". Things like buttons would definitely be View for me.

Comment: A ViewModel (model of the view), in the same lines of a presenter, should contain the "conceptual representation" (properties, behaviour, state) of the UI, while the "concrete representation" (the actual visible pixels) would be the View itself. At least that's how I understand it. Overall, I find the WPF terminology very, very confusing (redundant and ambiguous at the same time).